# Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '7/21/15' for column 'announced_on' at row 1

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-workbench, dbeaver

I am importing a flat file into a table in `DBeaver v7.0.2`. When I attempt to import, it's throwing an error for date field formatted as `mm/dd/yy`.

The date column in the table is defined with datatype `DATE`.

I receive the following error:

```
Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '7/21/15' for column 'announced_on' at row 1
```

Any ideas on why it's complaining about the date format? It appears that I do not need to explicitly specify date format in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

the normal date format is 2020-04-19.

If you try to insert 7/21/15 into a date field this will fail as you noticed.

Most imports allow to reformat input.

In mysql you would use STR_TO_DATE('7/21/15', '%m/%e/%y') to import data.

If you don't want to rewrite or need the dates that way , you could define the field as varchar(10) that is big enough to hold it.

Comment: @kms - Is that 1915 or 2015? Or 15 AD?  One should be aware of how (nondeterministic) the "2 to 4 year conversion" happens  The DB might even think it is 2115.  In short, never use 2 digit years.

Comment: this would be 2015 and we must wait till they tuc gets 64 bit finally, stiring data in a non mysql format is a bad design, because you can format every date in a format you like but for using date fuicntions you need a mysql date, so you have to convert it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('7/21/15', '%c/%e/%y') AS str_to_date
      ,CAST('7/21/15' AS date) as implicit_converstion
```

implicit conversion doesn't recognize your string as date